# How to deal with friend functions more appropriately?

Tags: c++, c++14

Below is the `String` class I've created with a constructor and a copy constructor. I've declared a class M which contains function `void print(String s);` , then I tried to make function print of class `M` as the friend of class `String` but it gives compile time error saying `M` does not exists. On the other hand if I make class `M` the friend of class `String` surprisingly the code works.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
class String{
private:
    char* str;
    size_t len;
public:
    String(char* str){
        len=sizeof(str)/sizeof(char);
        this->str=new char[(int)len];
        strcpy(this->str,str);
    }
    String(const String& s){
        if(str!=s.str)
        {
            strcpy(str,s.str);
            len=s.len;
        }
    }
    friend void M::print(String);//This line gives compile time error saying M does not exists.
    // friend class M;//This line on the other hand works completely fine when uncommented
};
class M{
public:
    void print(String s){
        cout<<s.str;
    }
};
int main()
{
    char x[6]={'H','e','l','l','o','\0'};
    String str=x;
    M a;
    a.print(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I applaud the effort you put into formatting the code fragments in the text, but the correct markup is using backticks (`\``), not bold (`**`). Fixed it for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ behavior is rather inconsistent in this matter. Making class `M` a friend would be equivalent to forward declaring this class. However making a method of that class a friend would require that class to be defined:

```
class String;

class M{
public:
    void print(String s);
};

class String { 
 // definition goes here...
  friend void M::print(String); // now works because compiler is aware of M::print
};

void M::print(String s)
{
   cout<<s.str;
}
```

Comment: could you please explain it a bit more

Comment: I disagree with the premise. `friend class M;` has enough information to forward declare a class. What would it mean to forward declare a class that _also_ has a specific member function? Would you have to error if it's later declared with out it?

Comment: @Barry As far as I know C++ does not allow forward declaring a class that *also* has a specific member function and referring to that function like `friend void M::print(String);` is only allowed if class `M` is complete.

Comment: @VTT Right, it does not - because it cannot. I don't think that's "inconsistent"

Comment: @VTT it still won't work because the prototype  void print(String s); contains String class as a formal parameter which is declared after the class M

Comment: @Sc00by_d00 It is declared prior to class M.

Comment: Thanks for help @VTT

Comment: @Barry Don't you think that it is inconsistent to have one kind of friend declaration that does two things: forward declares a class (because it can) and makes that class a friend, and another kind that does only one thing: makes some member function a friend?

Comment: @VTT: No, because that's actually normal. You can *define* a namespace-scoped function in a friend declaration too, with the whole of its implementation in the class. It's really no different from that. Of course, it's not called a "friend declaration" anymore; it's a "friend *definition*".

Comment: @NicolBolas Yeah, inconsistencies are pretty normal in C++.

Comment: @VTT: It would only be inconsistent if it were *possible* to forward declare a member function of a forward-declared class. But since that's actually impossible in the language, that's not a thing that friend declarations can do either. Also, it should be noted that `friend M` doesn't forward-declare `M`; only `friend class/struct M` would.